# Custom logic using Laravel with BackPack

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I would like to add a new entity in my DB and I have stuck thinking how should it be implemented in context of model relations and Laravel BackPack fields.

There was Actors and Directors models and they were using many-to-many relations with Movie model.

Now I would like to add Role entity as actor could be also a director in the same film. I created Persons model and bind it to Movie model like this (person_movie table with such fields: movie_id, person_id, role_id).

Questions:
**1. What kind of relation could it be?
2. How could it be implemented in BackPack Laravel?
3. Are there any approved solutions?**